# Creating dynamic URLS by concatenating strings rises UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, django, django-urls, url-pattern

I am trying to build my urls dynamically upon my project execution, it retrieves all my projects and concatenates the strings to create the urls like following:

```
for project in projects: 
    domain = Settings.objects.get(id_project=project).site_domain
    urlpatterns +=  patterns('',
    (r'^'+project.type+r'/'+project.name+r'/', include('apps.'+project.type+'.urls')))
```

The problem is that django is generating me this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in
>   position 144: ordinal not in range(128)

and when I take a look at the stack, there is nowhere pointing to my code.. I believe it has a relation to the `r'^'` which could be a different type of encoding, but I couldn't find resources to draw any conclusion.

Any help is extremely appreciated

Comment: You can safely replace `r'^'` and `r'/'` with `'^'` and `'/'`.  The `r` doesn't do anything unless there are backslashes in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Is that `patterns` a typo?

```
for project in projects: 
    domain = Settings.objects.get(id_project=project).site_domain
    urlpatterns +=  url(r'^'+project.type+r'/'+project.name+r'/', include('apps.'+project.type+'.urls'))
```

Comment: you got it! It was looking for actual enconding problems.. stack traces, misleading people for centuries.

Comment: It solved one part of the problem but now I have this: